# How to install package from Cygwin in command line?

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to use `setup-x86_64.exe` to install a package. But, in log, cygwin don't see package i want to install (`python37-3.7.4-1`):

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P python37-3.7.4-1 -N --no-admin

C:\cygwin>Starting cygwin install, version 2.897
User has NO backup/restore rights
Current Directory: C:\cygwin
Could not open Service control manager
root: C:\cygwin64 user
Selected local directory: C:\cygwin
net: Preconfig
site: http://cygwin.mirrors.hoobly.com/
HTTP status 404 fetching http://cygwin.mirrors.hoobly.com/x86_64/setup.zst.sig
HTTP status 404 fetching http://cygwin.mirrors.hoobly.com/x86_64/setup.zst
solving: 0 tasks, update: no, use test packages: no
Augmented Transaction List: is empty
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_000_autorebase.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash"
running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db
.sh"
Ending cygwin install
```

How use `setup-x86_64.exe` to install a package from command line ?

Comment: The log says it can not find some files on the hoobly.com mirror. Try another mirror site.

Comment: @DougHenderson how can i parameterize mirror ?

Comment: Use `setup-x86_64.exe -h` to show options.

Comment: There is no option permitting set mirror (see https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.cli)

Comment: There is a settings file. If you rerun, does it try another mirror? (I'm on phone now.) Maybe look for `/etc/setup.cfg` or something similar

Comment: I don't have. i run setup-x86_64.exe for first time (i'm creating a setup script for python application)

Comment: See -O and -s options. I use `-O -s http://mirrors.kernel.org` in my reinstall script.

Comment: Or maybe HTTPS instead of HTTP

Comment: No changes :/ I maybe will take a look on https://github.com/vegardit/cygwin-portable-installer

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem is simply the cygwin package name: use `python37` instead `python37-3.7.4-1`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this same issue is saving that setup-x86_64.exe file in a convenient location, and writing a batch file like so:

**"file_name_example.bat"** containing this:

```
C:\path\to\your\file\setup-x86_64.exe -M
```

I then saved that text in a file called "cygwin_package_manager.bat" on my desktop. So now I can just double click on that it's icon to run the package manager in "Semi-attended chooser-only mode". Meaning you don't have to manually click all the "OK" and "AGREE" stuff that you do running it the first time.

Bearing in mind though, it does take a while for that setup program to download the info it needs to sync up all your packages.

Cheers.